# Why doesn't strlen() return the correct number of bytes here?

Tags: objective-c, base64, byte

```
NSString* data = @"UdmAjkmNQs79+J/a/MVVSACRkIo=";
NSData *key = [NSData dataFromBase64String:data];
const char *keyBytes = [key bytes];
NSLog(@"Length:  %lu", strlen(keyBytes));
```

Consider the code above. I have a base64 string which contains 20 bytes of data. I turn it into bytes and I like to check the number of bytes. This prints 16. Why does it print 16 and what do I need to do to get the correct number of bytes (20)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code to get data byte length:

```
NSString* data = @"UdmAjkmNQs79+J/a/MVVSACRkIo=";
NSData *key = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:data options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
NSLog(@"Length:  %lu", [key length]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Also figured out the reason it doesn't always work with strlen() but occasionally does work. My example string in hex is 51D9808E498D42CEFDF89FDAFCC555480091908A. and that 00 near the end is a null terminator, therefore it saw only the first 16 bytes (or actually chars) with strlen()

Comment: yes its work in some cases so be careful to use `strlen()` with bytes or batter i suggest use `length` function of `NSData` for best result.